# Angular: Function returning value before the HTTP call is finished

Tags: angular, ajax, typescript, return

I have to calculate the total number of business days between selected dates and I am using the following logic

```
this.businessDays = this.calcBusinessDays(this.startDate, this.endDate);

calcBusinessDays(d1: Date, d2: Date) {
        let date1 = new Date(d1);
        let date2 = new Date(d2);
        let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        let difference = Math.floor((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / oneDay);
        let businessDays = 0;
        let i: number;
        this.httpService
            .getHolidays(moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(date2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) //start-date and end date are a part of query params in YYYY-MM-DD format.
            .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<HolidaysListInterface>) => {
                this.holidaysList = res.body.holidayDates;
                for (i = 0; i < difference; ++i) {
                    let day = date1.getDay();
                    let isHoliday = this.holidaysList.indexOf(moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) != -1;
                    if (day != 0 && day != 6 && !isHoliday) {
                        ++businessDays;
                    }
                    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                }
            });
        return businessDays;
    }
```

Now the problem here is I am getting `0` every time as a return value. The function is returning the value even before the Http call is finished. What's the workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is how asynchronous requests work. They are executed asynchronously disregarding the actual order of execution you specify. You could learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

One line solution to your problem is

> *anything that directly depend on the response from the HTTP call **should** be inside the subscription*

or in other words

> *subscribe where it's response is required*

One more thing to remember is you cannot return an async variable (`businessDays` here) synchronously.

Also you could use RxJS `map` operator to transform the response to your required format

Try the following

```js
businessDays: any;

someFunc() {
    this.calcBusinessDays(this.startDate, this.endDate).subscribe(
        businessDays => this.businessDays = businessDays,
        error => {
            // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
        }
    );
}

calcBusinessDays(d1: Date, d2: Date): Observable<any> { // <-- return observable here
    let date1 = new Date(d1);
    let date2 = new Date(d2);
    let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    let difference = Math.floor((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / oneDay);
    let businessDays = 0;
    let i: number;
    return this.httpService
        .getHolidays(moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(date2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) //start-date and end date are a part of query params in YYYY-MM-DD format.
        .pipe(
            map((res: HttpResponse<HolidaysListInterface>) => {
                this.holidaysList = res.body.holidayDates;
                for (i = 0; i < difference; ++i) {
                    let day = date1.getDay();
                    let isHoliday = this.holidaysList.indexOf(moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) != -1;
                    if (day != 0 && day != 6 && !isHoliday) {
                        ++businessDays;
                    }
                    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                }
                return businessDays; // <-- return modified value here
            })
        );
}
```